# Validating Select Options in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate a form selection box at [`THIS JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/Y6hCm/7/) Can you help me to use jquery to check if the Optins not selected or if the First option  `<option value="1">Select From The List</option>` selected then shows the error box and if it was correct to display the selected value in `#result`.

```
<form>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="1">Select From The List</option>
        <option value="2">First</option>
        <option value="3">Second</option>
        <option value="4">Third</option>
        <option value="5">Fourth</option>
    </select>
    <div id="error">Not selected!</div>
    <div id="valid">Validated!</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
</form>


#error { color:red; display:none; }
#valid{ color:green; display:none; }
```

Thanks

Comment: You should show some attempt of solving this to get help without downvotes here at SO. Also set your fiddle to be in the head and use the preferred jQuery lib. Lastly have value="" in your first option and 1 in the one with text First

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. You need to give it a try, and show your attempt. Then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6hCm/9/

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5m38D/1/

Comment: @Adeneo AND Arun, you do not necessarily want to generically preventDefault, only if nothing was selected

Comment: Thanks Arun and Adeneo

Comment: @mplungjan the problem is else the form will get submitted... but OP wants to show a particular response if valid item is selected

Comment: also see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5m38D/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/HNT37/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit( function(e) {
        var check=$('#mySelect').val();
        if ( check == '1' ) {
            $('#error').show();
            $('#valid').hide();
        }else{
            $('#error').hide();
            $('#valid').show();
        }
           e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please also let me know how to use the validation  in a true or false process? I mean i have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756241/how-to-call-for-after-validating-a-form, thanks

Comment: Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/C4d2Z/

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the `Options` not selected or if the First option selected without relating to values:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
        if(select.selectedIndex < 1){
            $('#error').show();
            $('#valid').hide();
        } else {
            $('#error').hide();
            $('#valid').show();
        }
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6hCm/12/)

Comment: And now explain your code please, selectedIndex<1 would work just fine.

Comment: @mplungjan oh, you're right, your solution is more complex..

Comment: You mean less complex :) Also `$("#error").toggle(error); $("#valid").toggle(!error);` where `var error=select.selectedIndex < 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is [JSFiddel Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6hCm/13/)

**JS**

```
$("#validate").on('click', function(e){
    var value=$("#mySelect").val(); //get selected value
    $(".validationStatus").hide(); //Hide all messages first
    if(value=="1")
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#error").show();
    }
    else
    {
        e.preventDefault(); // You can remove this when submitting page
        $("#valid").show();
    }
});
```

Please check the changes in HTML too. Added common class for validation messages. Added id to button

Comment: What a waste of code.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```
<form id="target" action="javascript:">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="1">Select From The List</option>
        <option value="2">First</option>
        <option value="3">Second</option>
        <option value="4">Third</option>
        <option value="5">Fourth</option>
    </select>
<div id="error">Not selected!</div>
    <div id="valid">Validated!</div>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <br />    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
</form>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////
scripts:

```
<script src="address of jquey.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#target").submit(function( event ) {
    displayVals();
});

});

function displayVals() {

    var singleValues = $( "#mySelect" ).val();

    if(singleValues == 1)
        $( "#error" ).css("display","block");

    else 
         $( "#valid" ).css("display","block");
  $( "#result" ).text(  singleValues );
}
</script>
```

///////////////////////////////
css:

```
#error { color:red; display:none; }
#valid{ color:green; display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dy8eq/)

Please note I made the 0th option empty so the values match the text in the select

```
$(function () {
  var validate = function() {
    var val = $('#mySelect').val(),error=val=="";
    $('#error').toggle(error);
    $('#valid').toggle(!error);
    return !error;
  }
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // only if you NEVER will want to submit
    validate();
    // or 
    // if (validate()) ...
  });
  $('#mySelect').on("change",function() {
    $("#result").html($(this).val());
    validate();
  });    
});
```