# How to Call for After Validating A Form

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a simple Form like [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/F2Ub3/8/). Now what I need is to call/check if the form has been validated or not to use the selected data later on. For example in following example. I used another button with id `validateTrueorFalse` to check weather the result of validation is True or False?

Can you please help me to figure this out?

Thanks!

```
<form>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="1">Select From The List</option>
        <option value="2">First</option>
        <option value="3">Second</option>
        <option value="4">Third</option>
        <option value="5">Fourth</option>
    </select>
    <div id="error">Not selected!</div>
    <div id="valid">Validated!</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
</form>

<button class="validateTrueorFalse">Check If Validate</button>
<div id="TruorFalese"></div>
```

Comment: I think you are confused... You said you have button with id 'valideeTruorFalese' but can see a div with that id

Comment: Sorry guys, I fix the fiddle

Comment: Where is the fixed fiddle ???

Comment: Oh my God ! I am lost here http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/F2Ub3/8/

Comment: Please never use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when you're not using the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You just define one variable to determine validate fail or successfully

See here for example :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var isValidate = false;
    $('form').submit( function(e) {
        var check=$('#mySelect').val()
        if ( check == '1' ) {
            $('#error').show();
            $('#valid').hide();
            isValidate = false;
        }else{
            $('#error').hide();
            $('#valid').show();
            isValidate = true;
        }
           e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#btnCheckValidated").click(function(){
        content = isValidate ? "Form is validated successfully" : "Form is validated failed";
        $("#valideeTruorFalese").html(content);    
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi fanfan, thanks for comment but it is not working! http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/F2Ub3/10/

Comment: Sorry, because I miss add `id="btnCheckValidated"` in button
`<button class="validateTrueorFalse">Check If Validate</button>` .
See http://jsfiddle.net/vqdat169/kKR6k/1/

Answer (score 0):

If u'll use `ajax` to send data after form is validated:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Ub3/4/)

If not u just need to see at POST array to get form values

If just check validation :

[demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Ub3/9/)

Comment: I am not sending any data to back end just if the selection made then do something, thats all

Comment: Thanks it works however it is always reterning value 2!

Comment: @Behseini not always... the value changes after clicking validate button